# Best way to create a search for custom post type by custom field values

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, search, query-posts

I have a custom post type called people.

I want to have 3 search fields for; first-name, middle-name and last-name

I was thinking about creating a page with my own search boxes and use query_posts:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_status' => 'publish' ,
                             'post_type' => array( 'people' ),
                             'meta_query' => array(
                                 array  (
                                     'key' => 'last-name',
                                     'value' => $last,
                                     'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                 ),
                                 array  (
                                     'key' => 'first-name',
                                     'value' => $first,
                                     'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                 ),
                                 array  (
                                     'key' => 'middle-name',
                                     'value' => $middle,
                                     'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                 )
                             )

                            )
                     ); ?>
```

Is this the correct way to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic query logic looks fine assuming you want an `AND` relationship between the first, middle, and last names but [`query_posts` is never, ever, ever the right way to do anything.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> Note: **This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes**. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. **query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic** way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query. **It is inefficient** (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
>   fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
>   pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
>   making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.

Create a new `WP_Query` object and use that instead.

```
$args = array(
  // your arguments as above
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if ($q->have_posts()) {
  while ($q->have_posts()) {
    $q->the_post();
    the_title(); // etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: ohh.. ok just as well I asked ;)     Would it be bad to replace the default archive (www.example/people/) with a template (archive-people.php) that handles this searching? Its just that an archive in this context is useless, or can it be disabled?

Comment: If you don't want the archive, register the post type without one, but you can create a custom archive template as well. Be aware that the main query will still run which could be a wasteful use of resources.